# Images and listings as non-floating figures

Tags: graphics, floats

I have been writing a large latex document, but I got some trouble with figures. Usually when I want to add an image or a listing to my list of figures, I just place it within `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}`. But the figure-environment is floating all the time and does not care about indentation. So, for some listings and images I use the minipage-environment to prevent floating. But the problem is, I don't know how to add those minipages to the list of figures.

A non-floating listing example:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=XML, 
label=lst:xsl_script, 
numbers=left, 
captionpos=b, 
caption=some caption]{documents/analyze.xml}
```

where analyze.xml is pretty short (5 lines) so I want it to be placed right here.

I know, I could surround it with `\begin{figure}[!htbp]` ...  `\end{figure}` and it would be placed at the position I want, but nevertheless the indentation would be messed up.

So my question is, how to add listings and images to the list of figures without surrouding them with a figure-environment?

Thanks.

Comment: you can use the capt-of package and put `\captionof{figure}{my caption}` in the `minipage` (it is `\caption` that writes to the list of figures), but please always post complete documents that show the problem, `figure` and `minipage` have the same behaviour with respect to indentation, so your description doesn't seem quite right and some other factor must be causing your problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you are completely right. I just have to use `\captionof{figure}{my caption}` together with `\captionsetup{type=figure}` within the minipage and it will be added to the list of figures as I wanted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \captionsetup{type=figure}
  \lstinputlisting[language=XML, numbers=left]{documents/analyze.xml}
  \caption{my caption}
  \label{fig:xsl_script}
\end{minipage}
```

Thanks to David and Axel.

Comment: Since you are using `\captionsetup{type=figure}` the regular caption command could be used, i.e. `\caption{my caption}` (instead of `\captionsetup{figure}{my caption}`)

Comment: Thank you, without `\captionsetup{type=figure}` the tex compiler threw an error, so it seems, I need it here in any way. I changed the code as you suggested.